# How to properly disable a mailman mailing list

Tags: postfix, mailman

I have been asked to disable a single mailing list on mailman. I do not want to destroy the list - we may want to revive it later. Also, we want to keep the archives accessible for the list members.

We are using mailman 2.1.14, with Postfix 2.9.6, on a VM running Ubuntu 12.04.

It seems that mailman does not have an option to disable a list. Searching the web, I found that I should instead solve this at the level of the MTA.
Specifically for Postfix, I found that I should [use header_checks](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2010-August/070042.html).
(For reference, I found a [similar advice](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2010-September/070284.html) for sendmail users).

I have updated the /etc/postfix/main_cf:

```
# Disable mailing lists
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre
```

And created an /etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre file containing:

```
/^Sender: <test-ml-bounces@example.com>/ REJECT
/^Sender: <real-ml-bounces@example.com>/ REJECT
```

(All mails come with "-bounces" attached to the Sender, for some reason).

Then I sent a mail to the test mailing list, and it did not arrive or appear in the archives - as intended.
A mail I had sent before changing the configuration had arrived in my mailbox and in the archives, also as intended.

The question is - is this a proper way of doing this? Or could this setup cause me trouble later on?

Answer (score 6):

It should be possible to remove the list's aliases from postfix by editing the `mailman/data/aliases` file (see [integrating postfix and mailman](http://www.list.org/mailman-install/postfix-integration.html))

Other options (from [this question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailman/+question/157154)):

- You could use the [emergency moderation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-admin/node14.html) feature of a mailing list to prevent any mail delivery (although the moderators would still receive emails if someone mails the list
- Change the rights on the list files: `chmod 000 lists/LISTNAME`, and when you want to re-enable the list, `chmod 2775 lists/LISTNAME`. If the list has public archives and you want to disable access to them, `rm archives/public/LISTNAME*`. When you re-enable the list, these symlinks will be automatically recreated when you access the list. In this case you may still want to remove the list's aliases from postfix as above